# Error "Multiple attachments set for the same contract" after implicit cordapp upgrade to new contracts version

Tags: corda

After implicit contract upgrade i got an error when execute tx - java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Multiple attachments set for the same contract.
the problem related to net.corda.core.transactions.TransactionBuilder.selectContractAttachmentsAndOutputStateConstraints method which detect groups contained more than one attachment for the same contract name.

To perform upgrade I have changed the version of the contracts, so I do not have contracts with the same version on the node.

In the table NODE_ATTACHMENTS_CONTRACTS  i really have the same CONTRACT_CLASS_NAME and different ATT_ID, however it should be in this way when I add new contract version (add jar to cordapps folder).

Such approach described in https://github.com/corda/samples/tree/release-V4/implicit-cordapp-upgrades and in the example it functioning well.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Normally Multiple attachments error is caused by incorrect project structures that have multiple sub-projects(with the same name) under the root project.

Unfortunately, without seeing your code, we cannot really see what is the issue with your code.

Thus, i would suggest you follow the sample and do it again, and consult with

1. our documentation at
   https://docs.corda.net/docs/corda-os/4.4/api-contract-constraints.html#implicit-vs-explicit-contract-upgrades
2. the contract upgrade article
   https://medium.com/corda/contract-upgrades-and-constraints-in-corda-425055a9a47f